# How to kill a unit test

Tags: unit-test, developer-console

I have a simple 2 test unit test class that I've executed before with no problem. I added another test method (making it 2 tests total) and ran the unit test from the dev console and it just runs and runs (it's been over an hour now and it usually takes around 10 sec to complete). Any way to kill a unit test?

Comment: Given Salesforce's multi-tenant limits, I'm surprised this is happening. Possibly more likely is there's some disconnect between your browser and the test server, so that either the test results aren't being returned and displayed, or the test run is being shown as being posted, but actually hasn't happened.

Answer (score 3):

Go to `force.com setup > Build > Develop > Apex Test Execution > Select your test and click on Abort`. It will solve your problem

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes requesting an abort of the unit test from the interface(going to Dev Console or Apex Test Execution) will not work.

In those instances you will have to query for the [ApexTestQueueItem](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm) objects that are stuck and switch the status to "Aborted" like so:

```
List<ApexTestQueueItem> items = [Select Id,ApexClassId,Status,ExtendedStatus,ParentJobId from ApexTestQueueItem where Status != 'Completed'];
for(ApexTestQueueItem atqi : items) {
    atqi.Status = 'ABORTED';
}
update items;
```

You can read more [here](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000384395&type=1).